# Continuous function defined on a Lebesgue integrable function?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable over $[a,b]$. Let $G(x)$ be defined for $x \in (a,b)$ by $$G(x) = \int_a^x f.$$ Is $G$ continuous? If not, find a counterexample.

How can I show this?

Comment: Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.